# CakePHP Regex Woes

Tags: regex, cakephp

I have a simple regex requirement for a route in CakePHP that is giving me trouble.

Routing code:

```
Router::connect('/tees/:id', array('controller' => 'tees', 'action' => 'view'), array('id' => "^.*[0-9].*[-][a-z].*$"));

regex: "^.*[0-9].*[-][a-z].*$"
```

Matched case: 340764-test-tee
Failed case: test
Failed case: anysingleword

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The solution I ended up using is as follows:

```
".*[0-9].*[a-z-].*"
```

Comment: You have to give a detailed format of matched case, otherwise, it is very hard to write the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to regex syntax you are requiring each match to include a '-' character ( the [-] in your regex) therefore any word without '-' will not match.
If you intended to do that then [-] is not the usual way, use \-
If you did NOT intend to match a '-' ALWAYS, maybe you wanted to add it to the [a-z], then the right syntax is:

```
^.*[0-9].*[a-z-].*$
```

But note thet [a-z-] will match only 1 character, you probably meant

```
^.*[0-9].*[a-z-]*$
```

or

```
^.*[0-9]*[a-z-]*$
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of those worked :(

The hyphen is really the key here, but my typical matched format would be "[numbers]-[alpha]" the string will always be prefixed by a set of numbers. There could be many sets of alpha following the numbers, though.

Comment: I ended up removing the caret and dollar sign, and it this worked perfectly. Thank you! `.*[0-9].*[a-z-].*`

Comment: Your regex contains ".*" at the beginning, meaning: anything can come before the numbers. :::: So the numbers appear only once, at the beginning? Use this regex then ^\d+(\-[a-z]+)*$

Comment: Still, if I understood correctly, the last regex will be better. Currently the input **45566-----** will match. (Unless you want it that way)